# Record-route header with lr=on when sent by Kamailio as Outbound proxy

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio, opensips

I am using Xlite at one end for sending INVITE.
If i use Kamailio 4.0.1 as outbound proxy,in the call flow it adds lr=on as mentioned below  WIRESHARK trace  :
Record-Route: 
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.44.104.149;branch=z9hG4bK0ecf.1bd4c266.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.44.104.160:5998;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-829f7d43eed09018-1---d8754z-;rport=5998

and after that the pbx sends 503 response for the INVITE.

but as per RFC 3665 for the call flow ,the lr should be blank as :
Record-Route:

is there any configuration change needed in the Kamailio  to meet REcord Route as per RFC 3665 ie lr without On value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set parameter **enable_full_lr** for **rr** module to 0, see:

- http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/rr.html#idp21848